# How to mention multiple pages with facebook posting API?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I would like to know how can I mention multiple pages with Facebook API. I can mention one page with API. Not able to mention multiple pages.
eg: test post @[page_id] -working
     test @[page_id1] posting for @[page_id2]-not working

Comment: Start by checking the “Tagging Ability” setting for that second page.

Comment: Hi it has tagging ability.But its tagging with only one page.is there anything else i have to do?
eg:  'message' => 'this is @[id1] and how are you @[id2]'

Comment: Are you in test mode, or did you already submit this feature for review?

Comment: yes. but i am using the administrator account pages. need to apply for the page mention permission.

Comment: If you turn this around, tag page2 first and page1 second, do you get the result reversed as well?

Comment: Hi Now i am not able to tag my admin account pages.is there any other settings i need to enable or may i wait for the permission to mention.